# How can I collect unclaimed dividends?

Tags: dividends, share-certificate

Suppose that decades ago, I owned shares in a public company, and held onto the stock certificates. Suppose the company never managed to pay me dividends because they could not locate me, and I never made any effort to collect the dividends. Where does the company store the dividends that belong to me? How can I claim the dividends now?

Further suppose that the company eventually went bankrupt. Do I lose all my unclaimed dividends?

Comment: Where in the world are you located, and where is (or was) the company headquartered? [This answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/109513/36669) addresses this issue in the US state of California, but that likely does not apply to you.

Comment: Contact the transfer agent. Its name should be on the certificates.  I would surmise that if the company is kaput and gone, so too are your unpaid dividends.